# Смешивание синтаксиса двух шаблонизаторов

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js, шаблоны

Появилась такая проблема, есть Django приложение. Частично хотел начать переписывать фронт на Vue, но встала проблема одинакового синтаксиса шаблонизаторов. {{ value }} используется в обоих фреймворках и вроде бы я где-то находил решение подобной проблемы, но к сожалению повторно найти не смог. Vue на первое время тянется из CDN, поэтому делать SPA пока не вариант.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кажется наиболее удобный способ - все Vue-шаблоны заключить в Django-теги: verbatim:

```
{% verbatim %}
<modal-dialog>{{header}}</modal-dialog>
{% endverbatim %}
```

Весь код внутри verbatim будет вставлен в результирующий html "как есть". Далее на стороне браузера Vue спокойно продолжит с ним работать

Comment: Хорошее решение, но с обилием vue это много избыточного кода.

Answer (score 5):

Есть два способа решить эту проблему.

1. На стороне Django: Использовать в шаблонах вместо `{{ some_varibale }}` монструозную конструкцию `{% templatetag openvariable %} some_varibale {% templatetag closevariable %}`
2. На стороне Vue: Переопределить разделители

   ```
   var app = Vue({
       el: '#app',
       delimiters: ['[[', ']]']
   });
   ```